# Looking for a way to get HTTP Digest Authentication headers from incoming http requests

Tags: cakephp, rest, digest, digest-authentication

I've been working on a REST implementation with my existing Cake install, and it's looking great except that I want to use HTTP Digest Authentication for all requests (Basic Auth won't cut it).  So great, I'll generate a header in the client app (which is not cake) and send it to my cake install.  Only problem is, I can't find a method for extracting that Digest from the request...

I've looked through the Cake API for something that I can use to get the Digest Header.  You'd think that Request Handler would be able to grab it, but I can't find anything resembling that.

There must be another method of getting the digest that I am overlooking?

In the meantime I'm writing my own regex to parse it out of the Request...  once I'm done I'll post it here so no one has to waste as much time as I did hunting for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  It's already accessible via PHP as `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_DIGEST']`

So then you pass to `parseDigestAuthData($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_DIGEST']);`

<bangs head against wall>

Comment: SecurityComponent can also handle digest authentication for you. Check out http://book.cakephp.org/view/1309/Basic-HTTP-Authentication and setting the type key to 'digest'.